# requestAnimationFrame flickering issue in Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, canvas, requestanimationframe

I am trying to animate a circle across the canvas in diagonal direction. I am using requestanimationframe. It works smoothly in all browsers but not in firefox. There is constant flickering while the animation is going on. Please someone tell me what wrong I am doing. I need smooth animatin with atleast reasonable speed in firefox.

Here is my simple code, maybe someone can point out what I am missing here..:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<style>
/*html { background: #000; }*/
</style>

<title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

    window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
      return  window.requestAnimationFrame       || 
              window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
              window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    || 
              window.oRequestAnimationFrame      || 
              window.msRequestAnimationFrame     || 
              function(/* function */ callback, /* DOMElement */ element){
                window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
              };
    })();

window.cancelRequestAnimFrame = ( function() {
    return window.cancelAnimationFrame          ||
        window.webkitCancelRequestAnimationFrame    ||
        window.mozCancelRequestAnimationFrame       ||
        window.oCancelRequestAnimationFrame     ||
        window.msCancelRequestAnimationFrame        ||
        clearTimeout
} )();  

var canvas, context, toggle;
var ctr = 0;
var request;

var x = 10;
var y = 10;


init();
animate();

function init() {

    canvas = document.createElement( 'canvas' );
    canvas.width = 512;
    canvas.height = 512;

    context = canvas.getContext( '2d' );

    document.body.appendChild( canvas );

}

function animate() {


    request = requestAnimFrame( animate );
    draw();

}

function draw() {

  context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
  y+=2;
  x+=2;

  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(x, y, 3, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  context.fillStyle = 'green';
  context.fill();
  context.lineWidth = 5;
  context.strokeStyle = '#003300';
  context.stroke();

    //cancelRequestAnimFrame(request); 

}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I was expecting a very quick reply to this question as the scenario is very straight forward. Is it not possible to have smooth html5 canvas animation in firefox?  Why is it so difficult to get it done in firefox, i wonder!

Comment: I'm not seeing this flickering in Firefox 18 on Mac.  What version of Firefox are you using?

Comment: I have just tried it in Firefox 18 on windows pc. It is not smooth. It works perfect in chrome but in Firefox I can see it is not smooth. Maybe this is the best Firefox can do. My client uses firefox so I must do something about this issue! In this example I have put a dead simple scenario of circle moving across canvas. My actual project contains image backgrounds and offcourse javascript logic in every loop iteration. In chrome,IE and safari all works well. Any ideas!!

Answer (score 2):

There are two things in your code which you need to be revised:

**First** try the new `requestAnimationFrame` polyfill.

```
(function() {
    var lastTime = 0;
    var vendors = ['ms', 'moz', 'webkit', 'o'];
    for(var x = 0; x < vendors.length && !window.requestAnimationFrame; ++x) {
        window.requestAnimationFrame = window[vendors[x]+'RequestAnimationFrame'];
        window.cancelRequestAnimationFrame = window[vendors[x]+
          'CancelRequestAnimationFrame'];
    }

    if (!window.requestAnimationFrame)
        window.requestAnimationFrame = function(callback, element) {
            var currTime = new Date().getTime();
            var timeToCall = Math.max(0, 16 - (currTime - lastTime));
            var id = window.setTimeout(function() { callback(currTime + timeToCall); }, 
              timeToCall);
            lastTime = currTime + timeToCall;
            return id;
        };

    if (!window.cancelAnimationFrame)
        window.cancelAnimationFrame = function(id) {
            clearTimeout(id);
        };
}())
```

For an in-depth explanation read this article: http://my.opera.com/emoller/blog/2011/12/20/requestanimationframe-for-smart-er-animating

The **second** is that you need to calculate the delta between one time stamp and the next one. You are working with a fixed value which on each rendering iteration got increased by one. Because your browser can not keep up the the pace it might happen to skip one or two frames. This way you get a smooth time.

This is the way you calculate the delta time:

```
end = Date.now();
delta = ( end - start ) / 1000.0 * 60;
end = start;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p5c6c/1/

Comment: Thanks for your post. Well I have tried this polyfill already and the animation was still not smooth as it should be. I did not know about the delta time which you mentioned. I see that you added the delta factor in my code..but unfortunately it am still have flickering on my firefox.damn firefox really. (Are you getting smooth animation using this code? if yes, which FF version!) I have read the article too but I can't get to know the secret of having smooth (as in other browsers) animation in firefox. I have been trying that for weeks now. I am totally stuck with firefox now.

Comment: FF 18.0.1. At first load is not as smooth as it should be (maybe this happens because the document is not rendered completely), but in the long time definitely got smoother compared with your approach, where i got skipped frames. The `window.onload = function()` i thick should resolve the problem.

Comment: Well the problem is still there on my side. My client's firefox also has the same issue. it is not totally smooth. my definition of smoothness is that how this animation behaves in chrome.

Comment: Then it's nothing to do with the code...anyway try to use delta time instead of fixed value...

Comment: yes there cant be anything wrong with just that piece of code. its just how badly FF handles the animation. I will try to find solution to my unique problem else where. thanks for your help anyways :)